# Is anyone still using Java? Can I have this translated please?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was looking for how to detect if an Android Q device has Dark Mode enabled, and the only result I found was in Kotlin:

```
fun isDarkTheme(activity: Activity): Boolean {
    return activity.resources.configuration.uiMode and
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

IF it is correct, then can I please have it in Java? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the java Version

```
private Boolean isDarkTheme(Activity activity) {
    return (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
```

**Java** `getResources()` ->**Kotlin** `resources`

**Java** `getConfiguration()` ->**Kotlin** `configuration`

**Java** `&` ->**Kotlin** `and`

as you see it's simple Setters and Getters in koltin are accessed by property name

Answer (score 1):

I realised there might be a little more going on here to someone who's completely unfamiliar with Kotlin, so just in case:

```
boolean isDarkTheme(Activity activity) {
    return activity.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

all the `get` calls get converted to property syntax in Kotlin, so you can just access them like fields. The rest of the stuff just moves around a bit

Comment: Mohammed's right, ``and`` is ``&`` not ``&&`` so looks like this was trickier than I thought! Also I didn't test it so uh... feel free to check and upvote Mohammed's answer if it works. I think people were voting you down because it looks like someone who knows Java should be able to work out how you move stuff around in the signature, and sometimes people post questions where they haven't even looked at the problem and they're just "someone do this" so people get jumpy!